# LaTeX openright not correct

Tags: books

I'm trying to start chapters on the right page. This is in my preamble:

`\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}`

I am also using the `showframe` package to show me the frames. LaTeX sees my first page (which is actually the "cover" of the book) as a left page, and starts every chapter on a left page, according to the `showframe` outputs... In fact, I read somewhere that odd pages are always right pages in LaTeX, but for me they are left pages in my viewer?

Could this be because I'm using includes for my different chapters?

Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: They look like right pages to me. It may be that your viewer is confused with the view because you changed the page numbering scheme.

Comment: My viewer (Preview) shows the first page as a single page, and subsequent pages as two pages next to each other. This is indeed what I want, because the first page is the cover of the book. I'll check if changing the numbering scheme alters anything.

Comment: Disabling the Roman page numbering fixes my problem. However, I'm required to use Roman numbering for everything before the first chapter. I'll look a bit further, but I think it's quite odd that this occurs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by an issue not mentioned in the posting itself and not related to the information provided in the posting.

Answer (score 2):

I had included a PDF (the cover) before setting my paging to Roman numerals. This made it so that odd pages were actually on the left and not on the right. Moving the Roman page numbering command before the PDF include fixed the problem.